# How and when to use aura:systemError

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Has anyone used aura:systemError in their lightning component ?
I have used aura:systemError for handling exception generated in associated controller.
I included -
 A ui button that throws NullPointerException whenever clicked and a event handler - 
`<aura:handler event="aura:systemError" action="{!c.showSystemError}"/>` in my component.On the click of button the associated js function never gets called.I get no alerts, no console logs nothing !
However in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_systemError.htm) it is clearly written -

> This event is automatically fired when an error is encountered during
>   the run of a server-side action

Is it is something I am misinterpreting? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Once that event fires in your server side controller, your client side controller needs to decide what to do with it, or how to handle it. You can choose to "trap" it which is essentially what we do in Apex via a try-catch block when we don't allow an exception to crash an app and often don't even display it. You can also choose to display an error message in a component if you wish.

In the example code in the docs you've linked to you'll note that they've partially written a function as below:

```
showSystemError: function(cmp, event) {
   // Handle system error
   $A.log(cmp);
   $A.log(event); 
}
```

In the above they've written the data to the regular console log. Unless you're in debug mode, the user won't have access to the data and will never see it.

When in Production Mode, there are only a few ways that they'll ever be able to access the above date or see it. Which, if any, of those occurs is totally up to you.

1. Use `$A.logger.subscribe(String level, function callback)` to create custom logging messages that will appear in the console. However, these messages still won't directly display to the user.
2. Use `$A.warning(string)` to write a custom warning message to the JS console. Again, these still won't directly display to the user, but will be visible to them in the console.
3. To actually display a message to the user, you'll need to define an event for it and create a component that can display the event when it fires. In essence, it's up to you to decide how to handle these things, including how you want it displayed. You could even use a section in the above code to create a dynamic component that would display the system error to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I do not reply to very core of my question! Why this showSystemError js function dint get called at all?

showSystemError: function(cmp, event) {
   // Handle system error
   /* This method does not gets called at all!! */
   alert('System error is thrown '); /*No alert comes up */
   console.log('System error in console log'); /* No console log appears*/
   $A.log(cmp);  /* No log is visible at UI end*/
   $A.log(event); 
}

Comment: Have you enabled Lightning Debug Mode? If not, you won't see those error messages in the console. You also need add code that puts it in browser debug mode to see those error messages. I highly recommend you review the [Trailhead Lightining Components Module - Debugging Components Challenge Section](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_intermediate/lightning_components/lightning_components_debug) which explains all this quite well.